# Property 'foods' is private and only accessible within class 'MainLifecycleComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, atributos, angular-8, private

Como acessar atributos privados dentro do html? Criei o private food, mas não consigo acessar ele no html por ser privado. tem alguma forma de acessar?

main-lifecycle.ts

```
import { Client } from '../client';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-lifecycle',
  templateUrl: './main-lifecycle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-lifecycle.component.css']
})
export class MainLifecycleComponent implements OnInit {
  private clients: Client[] = [];
  private foods : string [] = ["Rice", "Beans", "Pizza"];
  private name: string = "";
  private age: number;
  private food: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

main-lifecycle.html

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>
      Clients
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
        <section>
            <mat-form-field class="form-field" style="width: 400px; padding-right: 20px;" >
                <input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="form-field" style="width: 100px; padding-right: 20px" >
                <input matInput placeholder="Age" [(ngModel)]="age" name="age">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field >
                <mat-select placeholder="Favorite Food" [(ngModel)]="food" name = "food ">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let foodOption of foods" [value]="foodOption">
                        {{foodOption}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <button mat-icon-button color="primary" >
                <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
            </button>

            <button mat-icon-button color="primary" >
                <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </section>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Sim, quando insere private em um atributo na classe, não consegue utilizá-lo em nenhum outro lugar a não ser na própria classe. Só não entendi o pq do private!

Comment: nem eu entendi, na real. o professor que colocou desse jeito, mas de alguma forma o dele foi e o meu não. ele conseguiu acessar no html dessa forma, mas aqui no meu não...

Comment: É assim, não consegue utilizar em outros lugares se for pensar em orientação a objetos puro, como nas linguagens Java e C#. No JavaScript (TypeScript) isso na verdade não é real, pq consegue declarar um atributo private e utilizá-lo no HTML, consegue acessar a propriedade normalmente, a minha IDE por exemplo aponta o erro: **Private field foods cannot be resolved when using the AOT compiler.**, isso é um warning da IDE, mas consigo ver o valor da propriedade foods na tela. Na onde que apontou esse erro: **Property 'foods' is private and only accessible within class 'MainLifecycleComponent'**?

Comment: ele apontou na pro foods. o array que tá carregando algumas comidas